# mv command is throwing too many arguments in SOLARIS

Tags: unix, solaris, mv

```
for f in `find /app/rohith/* -type f -o -prune  -name "*.*"` ; mv $f /app/arch/; done
```

ERROR:
ksh: /usr/bin/find: arg list too long

---

Note :
-> OS is Solaris
-> So, i am using prune here, its similar to maxdepth

My Query : How to move only files(not the sub directories) from /app/rohith/ to /app/arch/ in SOLARIS, and also it should not give too many arguments error/exception.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
find /app/rohith/* -type f -prune  -name "*.*" -exec mv {} /app/arch/ \;
```

I am not sure if it works on solaris but on linux it does

Comment: No. I tried all these. But, Noooo..! Not working on SOLARIS.

Comment: So what is the outcome of this cmd ? Could you paste the output ?

Comment: This command is syntactly correct under Solaris like under Gnu/Linux, but the issue is the number of files under /app/rohith. It might equally fail under Linux if the file list doesn't fit in the environment.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, unless you have files with really odd names:

```
cd /app/rohith && ls | while read name; do [ -f "$name" ] && mv "$name" /app/arch ; done
```